# "Unhandled rejection" error in Aurelia Fetch Client

Tags: javascript, fetch, aurelia

I use Aurelia Fetch Client library to fetch JSON data from the backend server by the code:

```
getData() {
    let httpClient = new HttpClient();

    return httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:9220/get-data')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => return data);
    }
}
```

And the metod `getData()` is called from the another code by the code:

```
dataService.getData().then(data => {
    this.data = data;
}).catch(error => {
    this.backendError = true;
});
```

As you can see I use here a `catch` statement and in case of error it's called, but I also see in the console an error message that comes from the library: "*vendor-bundle.js:1395 Unhandled rejection TypeError: Failed to fetch*". How can I get rid it?

Comment: The error will be being caused because the API you're trying to call is failing.

Comment: Yes I know, but there is any way to handle this error?

Comment: if my answer solved your query - please mark it as accepted. Or, if didn't, let me know so I can edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure if this is a bug with the Aurelia HTTP Fetch Client, but adding a `responseError` interceptor should remove the Unhandled Exception warning in the console.

```
let http = new HttpClient();

http.configure(config => {
    config.withInterceptor({
        response(response) {
            return response;
        },
        responseError(error) {
            return error;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may also come from the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` middleware in a .NET Core API. This middleware strips all headers from the response which create CORS issues and causes the "TypeError: Failed to fetch" error you saw. Here is an example of my solution, which is described in full [here](https://blog.jonathaneckman.io/handling-net-core-web-api-exceptions-with-an-aurelia-fetch-interceptor/).

### .NET Core Middleware

```
private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
    var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = "An internal server error has occurred." });
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
    return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
}
```

### Aurelia Interceptor

```
responseError(response: any): Promise<Response> {
    if (response instanceof Response) {
        return response.json().then((serverError: ServerError) => {

             // Do something with the error here.

             return Promise.reject<Response>(serverError.error);
        }); 
    }
}
```